# remove active song from media session in android

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

I have an app that is using the Android MediaSession and MediaBrowserConnection to play songs and have a playlist. I am a bit stuck on how to remove the current playing song when someone wants to clear the entire playlist. I can easily remove all of the remaining songs from the queue like so...

```
for(MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem item : mediaControllercompat.getQueue()) {
  mediaControllerCompat.removeQueueItem(item.getDescription());
}
```

Where mediaControllercompat is a MediaControllerCompat object.

But I can't find an easy way to remove the song that is actively playing. The above just removes any songs that are in the queue, and not the active song.

I think I can kind of fake it by just forcing the "skip" feature and since the playlist is empty it would stop playing, but I was wondering if that is the correct way to do that, or if there was a better way to handle it.

I would be more than happy to show any relevant code if needed. I am just not sure what code is needed exactly, since there are a good 9 or so classes not including the classes inside classes for callbacks and whatnot. Please let me know if I need to show anything else. Thank you.